# EXE made with PyInstaller can't load libvlc.dll (python-vlc)

Tags: python, pyinstaller, vlc, python-vlc

I'm trying to package a python script which uses python-vlc using pyinstaller, but the resulting .exe refuses to recognize the libvlc.dll binary file. I always get the same error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctypes\__init__.py", line 381, in __init__
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "vlc-test.py", line 3, in <module>
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 975, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 671, in _load_unlocked
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 495, in exec_module
  File "vlc.py", line 210, in <module>
  File "vlc.py", line 170, in find_lib
  File "PyInstaller\loader\pyimod04_ctypes.py", line 55, in __init__
pyimod04_ctypes.PyInstallerImportError: Failed to load dynlib/dll '.\\libvlc.dll'. Most likely this dynlib/dll was not found when the application was frozen.
[2236] Failed to execute script 'vlc-test' due to unhandled exception!
```

Which seems to be a problem others have fixed by including either binary or data files in the spec file. Nothing I add to the spec file makes any difference, though. Here's where it is now, I've even included Windows system dlls that the VLC one depends on:

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

block_cipher = None

a = Analysis(['vlc-test.py'],
             pathex=["D:\\GitHub\\hours", "C:\\Users\\zacha\\anaconda3\\envs\\hours\\Lib\\site-packages"],
             binaries=[("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\libvlc.dll","."),
                ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\libvlccore.dll","."),
                ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\axvlc.dll","."),
                ("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\npvlc.dll","."),
                ("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\advapi32.dll","."),
                ("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\kernel32.dll","."),
                ("C:\\Windows\\SysWOW64\\MSVCRT.dll","."),
                ],
             datas=[('./libvlc.dll', '.'), ('./axvlc.dll', '.'), ('./libvlccore.dll', '.'), ('./npvlc.dll', '.')],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             hooksconfig={},
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)

a.datas += Tree("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\VideoLAN\\VLC\\plugins", prefix='plugins')
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)

exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts, 
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='vlc-test',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True,
          disable_windowed_traceback=False,
          target_arch=None,
          codesign_identity=None,
          entitlements_file=None )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas, 
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               upx_exclude=[],
               name='vlc-test')
```

All the files listed under binaries do indeed appear in the dist folder, so I don't think it's a formatting issue. I'm using 32-bit versions of both Python and VLC. Is there anything else I can try before giving up?

Windows 11, Python 3.8.8, pyinstaller 4.9

Answer (score 0):

I see you've already added libvbc.dll, have you tried adding it through binaries in this way?

```
a.binaries + [("libVLC.dll", "D:\KivySchool\VLC\libvlc.dll", "BINARY")],
```

Also try

```
    pathex=["D:\KivySchool\VLC"],
```

working vlctest.py:

```
from sys import platform

if platform == "win32": #https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.platform
    import vlc
    import os
    import time

    vlc_player = vlc.MediaPlayer() 
    medianame = "bigbuckbunny x265.mp4"
    mediapath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), medianame)
    media = vlc.Media(mediapath)
    vlc_player.set_media(media)
    vlc_player.play()
    offset = 5
    time.sleep(offset)
    length = vlc_player.get_length() #time in ms (divide by 1000 to get in seconds)
    newoffset = length/1000 - offset
    time.sleep(newoffset)
```

This is a working .spec file for Windows, using x64 VLC and PyInstaller `6.3.0`.

```
# -*- mode: python ; coding: utf-8 -*-

medianame = "bigbuckbunny x265.mp4"

a = Analysis(
    ['basicpyvlc.py'],
    pathex=["D:\KivySchool\VLC"],
    binaries=[("D:\KivySchool\VLC\plugins\*", "plugins")],
    datas=[(medianame, ".")],
    hiddenimports=[],
    hookspath=[],
    hooksconfig={},
    runtime_hooks=[],
    excludes=[],
    noarchive=False,
)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure)

exe = EXE(
    pyz,
    a.scripts,
    a.binaries + [("libVLC.dll", "D:\KivySchool\VLC\libvlc.dll", "BINARY")],
    a.datas,
    [],
    name='basicvlc',
    debug=False,
    bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
    strip=False,
    upx=True,
    upx_exclude=[],
    runtime_tmpdir=None,
    console=True,
    disable_windowed_traceback=False,
    argv_emulation=False,
    target_arch=None,
    codesign_identity=None,
    entitlements_file=None,
)
```

example repo (because I spent 3 days getting this to work on Win AND Mac, also made sure they work even if VLC is not installed previously): https://github.com/AccelQuasarDragon/BasicPyVLC